# How to calculate the sum of two different fields in a SoQL query

Tags: bash, soql

I'm making a query in soql to calculate the mean value of two numeric fields H01 and H02 in a json file, whose values are 6 and 4, respectively. This query gets a single record. The query is like this:

```
query="SELECT H01,H02, $((H01 + H02))/2 AS AVERAGE WHERE pollutant = 'H6' AND DATA = '2020-05-08T00:00:00.000' AND location = 'London'"
```

However, when executing this query, the AVERAGE value gives 0, when in fact it is 10.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You must include the `/2` within `$(( ))` as in:

```
$(( (H01 + H02) / 2 ))
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ H01=6;H02=4; echo $(( (H01 + H02) /2 ))
5
```

#### Note - This does *not* work for floating point

```
$ H01=5;H02=4; echo $(( (H01 + H02) /2 ))
4
```

Comment: Thank you @SiegeX for your answer. If I had two decimal numbers, what would be the expression? For example: `query="SELECT H01,H02, $(( (H01 + H02) /2 )) AS AVERAGE WHERE pollutant = 'H6' AND DATA = '2020-05-08T00:00:00.000' AND location = 'London'"` if the values of H01 and H02 are 0.6, respectively, the result of AVERAGE is 5, not 0.6